# Getting an OutOfBounds exception after reading a csv file into an array

Tags: java, arrays, csv, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing a program that takes a csv file, and reads each of the lines into an array of USCrimeClass objects that have their own field. I want to see if the arrays are being made correctly by printing one of them out, but I am getting an OutOfBounds exception.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class USCrimeClass
{
    public int year;
    public int population;
    public int violentCrime;
    public double violentCrimeRate;
    public int manslaughter;
    public double manslaughterRate;
    public int rape;
    public double rapeRate;
    public int robbery;
    public double robberyRate;
    public int assault;
    public double assaultRate;
    public int propertyCrime;
    public double propertyCrimeRate;
    public int burglary;
    public double burglaryRate;
    public int larcenyTheft;
    public double larcenyTheftRate;
    public int vehicleTheft;
    public double vehicleTheftRate;

    public USCrimeClass(String line)
    {
        String[]split=line.split(",");
        year=Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
        population=Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        violentCrime=Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
        violentCrimeRate=Double.parseDouble(split[3]);
        manslaughter=Integer.parseInt(split[4]);
        manslaughterRate=Double.parseDouble(split[5]);
        rape=Integer.parseInt(split[6]);
        rapeRate=Double.parseDouble(split[7]);
        robbery=Integer.parseInt(split[8]);
        robberyRate=Double.parseDouble(split[9]);
        assault=Integer.parseInt(split[10]);
        assaultRate=Double.parseDouble(split[11]);
        propertyCrime=Integer.parseInt(split[12]);
        propertyCrimeRate=Double.parseDouble(split[13]);
        burglary=Integer.parseInt(split[14]);
        burglaryRate=Double.parseDouble(split[15]);
        larcenyTheft=Integer.parseInt(split[16]);
        larcenyTheftRate=Double.parseDouble(split[17]);
        vehicleTheft=Integer.parseInt(split[18]);
        vehicleTheftRate=Double.parseDouble(split[19]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner read = null;
        {
            try
            {
                read=new Scanner(new File("C:\\Crime.csv"));
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("The file can't be opened");
                System.exit(0);
            }



            String[] lines = null;

            read.nextLine();
            while(read.hasNextLine())
            {
                lines=read.nextLine().split(",");
            }

            USCrimeClass[] CrimeYear=new USCrimeClass[lines.length];

            for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++)
            {
                CrimeYear[i]=new USCrimeClass(lines[i]);
            }
            read.close();

            System.out.println(CrimeYear[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what the csv file should look like

```
1994,260327173,1130,3.7,3890,39.5,...
1995,250692382,2478,21.5,2230,28.6,...
1996,230492492,4092,22.8,3202,39.4...
```

And here is the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at USCrimeClass.<init>(USCrimeClass.java:30)
at USCrimeClass.main(USCrimeClass.java:84)
```

Comment: So where is this exception occuring?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the Crime.csv file is supposed to look like and where the error is coming from? I tried guessing what the file should look like and making my own example to debug, but it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: The error is occurring at lines 30 and 84. As for what it looks like, it has headings for each category (which is skipped when the array is made), then for each row, it has the year, population, and multiple crime activities and the rate in which they occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding this code:

```
while(read.hasNextLine())
{
    lines = read.nextLine().split(",");
}
```

what you are doing here is reading the file line by line, but you are always overwriting `lines` with the currently read line. In the end `lines` will only contain the split contents of the last line and not all lines in the csv file.

Add each read line to a list and then this should work:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

read.nextLine();
while(read.hasNextLine())
{
    lines.add(read.nextLine());
}

USCrimeClass[] CrimeYear = new USCrimeClass[lines.size()];

for(int i=0;i<lines.size();i++)
{
    CrimeYear[i]=new USCrimeClass(lines.get(i));
}
read.close();
```

In case you don't want to buffer all the read lines, you can also directly create the corresponding objects:

```
List<USCrimeClass> crimeClasses = new ArrayList<>();
read.nextLine();
while(read.hasNextLine())
{
    crimeClasses.add(new USCrimeClass(read.nextLine()));
}

read.close();

System.out.println(crimeClasses.get(0));
```

BTW: I'd also recommend putting the read.close() into a `finally { ... }` block.

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question; if I wanted to make a method that returns the year of a specified item in the array list, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Each element of the list is a `USCrimeClass` object. So `crimeClasses.get(0)` returns a `USCrimeClass` object on which you can just call it's methods or access its fields, e.g. `crimeClasses.get(0).year`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks again!